# problems with java and google api calendar

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

I’m working with java and google api calendar, but when I try to create the object calendar with this code :

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
```

The console show me the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient.<init>(Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonObjectParser;Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/GoogleClientRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:135)
    at com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar$Builder.build(Calendar.java:4603)
    at cl.packg.Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:162)
```

Additional information:

For **HTTP_TRANSPORT** variable, I’m using this: `com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport`.

For **JSON_FACTORY** variable, i’m using this:  `com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory`.

And for **credential** variable, i’m using this : `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Calendar insert method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), the sample to create calendar was provided:

```
 Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
        .setApplicationName("applicationName").build();

    // Create a new calendar
    com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.setSummary("calendarSummary");
    calendar.setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");

    // Insert the new calendar
    Calendar createdCalendar = service.calendars().insert(calendar).execute();

    System.out.println(createdCalendar.getId());
```

Your code seems to be missing the `.setApplicationName("applicationName")` part.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, i tried to create the Calendar object using setApplicationName, but i get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to run this [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java)  first?